# pairwise_cor with grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have from the [tidytuesday](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday) project the [scripts of all Friends episodes](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/tree/master/data/2020/2020-09-08)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytuesdayR)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor
library(widyr)
library(tidytext)

tt <- tt_load("2020-09-08")
#> --- Compiling #TidyTuesday Information for 2020-09-08 ----
#> --- There are 3 files available ---
#> --- Starting Download ---
#> 
#>  Downloading file 1 of 3: `friends.csv`
#>  Downloading file 2 of 3: `friends_info.csv`
#>  Downloading file 3 of 3: `friends_emotions.csv`
#> --- Download complete ---


library(glue)

episodes <- tt$friends_info %>%
mutate(full_title = glue("{ season }.{ episode } { title }"),
      full_title = fct_reorder(full_title, season + .001 * episode))

friends <- tt$friends %>%
inner_join(episodes, by = c("season", "episode"))


main_cast <- friends %>%
count(speaker, sort = TRUE) %>%
head(6)


friends %>%
unite(scene_id, season, episode, scene) %>%
count(speaker, scene_id) %>%
semi_join(main_cast, by = "speaker") %>%
pairwise_cor(speaker, scene_id, n, sort = TRUE) %>%
mutate(item2 = reorder_within(item2, correlation, item1)) %>%
ggplot(aes(correlation, item2)) +
geom_col(aes(fill = item1), show.legend = FALSE) +
scale_y_reordered() +
facet_wrap(~ item1, scales = "free_y") +
labs(x = "Correlation between characters appearing in a scene",
    y = "Other character")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would like to recreate that image but grouping by season
My problem is that the result of `pairwise_cor()` removes information on `season` and doing a `group_by()` before `pairwise_cor()` does not lead to aggregation by `season`.

How can I evaluate the same plots but for each season separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by nesting your data by season, running `pairwise_cor` via `map` on the resultant `data` column, then unnesting.

It's difficult to know how you want the final plot to look (since it would have 60 different panels), so here is an example of using all 10 seasons worth of data for a faceted heatmap:

```r
friends %>%
  unite(scene_id, episode, scene) %>%
  count(speaker, season, scene_id) %>%
  semi_join(main_cast, by = "speaker") %>%
  nest(data = -season) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, 
                    ~pairwise_cor(.x, speaker, scene_id, n, sort = TRUE)
                    )) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>%
  mutate(season = factor(paste('Season', season), paste('Season', 1:10))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(item1, item2, fill = correlation)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~ season, nrow = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]